# Rails throwing error instead validating

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation

I am building a fairly straightforward Rails 5 application. You create "Movies," and then can create "Reviews" for those movies. Rails is doing something odd. I have my application set up so instead of a "new" action and a corresponding view, I have the form to create new movies in a modal contained in the application.html.erb file. I then provide @newmovie = Movie.new in the controller for all the movie views, so the data is available everywhere.

I have validations for the movie object setup like this:

```
 class Movie < ApplicationRecord
   has_many :reviews 
   validates :title, :director, :poster, :synopsis, presence: true
 end
```

When I fill out the form to create a new movie in the modal on my index view and intentionally leave fields blank (to trigger the validation), I get this:

[image]

instead of the form simply not accepting the input. What's going on here? I can't have this error happening like this. Previously, I had a "new" view. This did not happen in the previous setup. Help!

Here is my entire movies controller:

```
class MoviesController < ApplicationController

    before_action :find_movie, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy ]
    before_action :authenticate_user!, only: [:new, :create, :edit, :update, :destroy]
    before_action :find_newmovie, only: [:show, :index, :new, :edit]

    def show
        @reviews = @movie.reviews.all.order(created_at: :desc).paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page => 3)
        @review = Review.new
        if @movie.reviews.blank?
            @average_review = 0
        else
            @average_review = @movie.reviews.average(:rating).round(2)
        end
    end 

    def index 
        @movies = Movie.all.order(title: :asc).paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page => 3)
        @newmovie = Movie.new
    end 

    def new
        @movie = Movie.new
    end 

    def create
        @movie = Movie.create(movie_params)
        @movie.user_id = current_user.id
        if @movie.save
            flash[:success] = "Your movie was created!"
            redirect_to root_path
        else
            flash[:danger] = "There was a problem with your request"
            render :new 
        end 
    end 

    def edit

    end 

    def update 
        if @movie.update(movie_params)
            flash[:success] = "Your movie was updated"
            redirect_to movie_path 
        else 
            flash[:danger] = "There was a problem with your request"
        end
    end 

    def destroy 
        if @movie.destroy
            flash[:success] = "Your movie was removed"
            redirect_to movies_path 
        else 
            flash[:danger] = "There was a problem with your request"
            render :index
        end 
    end 

    private 

        def movie_params 
            params.require(:movie).permit(:title, :director, :poster, :synopsis, :user_id)
        end 

        def find_movie 
            @movie = Movie.find(params[:id])
        end 

        def find_newmovie
            @newmovie = Movie.new
        end

end
```

Comment: You need to create a new instance of a movie before you can use it in a form and assign it to `@newmovie`. That should happen in your controller somewhere.

Comment: Need to know what your routes are set to. Does your failing form come from `new` or `index`? Unclear... If `new`, then you aren't setting `@newmovie` in the `new` method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `new` action of `movies_controller`, you missed to initalize the instance variable `@newmovie`.

add below code in `movies_controller`:

```
  class MoviesController < ApplicationController
    def new
      @newmovie = Movie.new
    end
   ...
  end
```

Comment: I actually have already. I updated the question a bit to include that.

Comment: It's up. Thanks for the help.

Comment: try `<%= form_for Movie.new do |m| %>`

Comment: @JSeabolt vote and accept my answer if it helps you. Thanks

Comment: Yes, the answer is <%= form_for Movie.new do |m| %> Thank you sir.